# Military personnel funds transfer scam

Tags: fraud, scams, usaa

I was contacted by someone who claims he is in the military stationed overseas. He said he could transfer fund from his account to mine. Just wondering if this is true. I am not interested in transfering funds.

Comment: This is a classic scam, stay as far away as possible from it.

Comment: And of course this someone needed to get your bank account number so that he could arrange the transfer from his account to yours?

Answer (score 26):

Nobody legitimate is going to call you unexpectedly and ask you to participate in some financial transaction. Period.

This could be any one of several styles of scam, depending on details you haven't given us. But it really doesn't matter; they're all scams.

http://www.consumer.ftc.gov/scam-alerts

http://www.consumer.ftc.gov/articles/0076-phone-scams